# Can I change my .onion address name?

Tags: onion-routing

So I already created a .onion site but I want to change my address to something else, that is more than just symbols. I tried using shallot but that is not working and when I tried to install or find scallion and eschalot it did not go well. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: I'd say Scallion or Eschalot, which you've already mentioned, are your best bet. (Other users may know of other services, but they'll presumably work in a very similar way.) When you say finding/installing them "didn't go well", what problems are you having?

Comment: I tried to install scallion but it did not work and I could not find eschalot

Comment: Are you based on Windows or Linux? Eschalot is [here](https://github.com/ReclaimYourPrivacy/eschalot), but Linux-only.

Comment: I'm linux based

Comment: Eschalot is working for me. (I cloned a fresh instance from the Git repository.) Give that a go.

Comment: a little bit older but have a look here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29772/how-do-you-get-a-specific-onion-address-for-your-hidden-service

Comment: I finally got shallot and eschalot working so thank you! It hasn't finished searching the words I want but thats because they are around 12-15 characters long. After I use them do you guys know how I change my .onion address to that address?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have your private key, you should put it in your hidden service dir. There is a file in there named "private_key". This is the file you replace with the new key.
I'm not sure if it's necessary, but I would also delete the "hostname" file. A new one should get generated.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [scalion](https://github.com/lachesis/scallion) or something else to generate your keys. Your keys ARE binded to the address you've generated, no matter the way you've done it. So if you want to switch address - you need to re-generate your key. And - a word of warning. UNLESS your previous keys were hijacked by bad guys - put a redirect on the old address you've used. Just make it to preserve links unbroken.